# Eclipse does not confirm exit when hitting command + q

Tags: eclipse, macos, quit

I generally close tabs while using Eclipse with `command`+`w`, however, sometimes hit `command`+`q` by mistake. Even though I have Eclipse set-up to warn me when exiting (Preferences -> General -> Start-up and Shutdown, "Confirm exit when closing last window"), this shortcut seems to bypass the warning, which is quite annoying.

Is there a solution to this same as the way Chrome presents a warning when hitting this shortcut? A hack in some `plist` file maybe? Google searches have not helped much.

Comment: Command+q pops a confirmation dialog for me just fine (Indigo Release, JEE build). Are you positive your 'Confirm exit when closing last window' option is checked?

Comment: @Perception Yes, I should mention I am using Juno.

Comment: This is similar to [bug 318177](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=318177), with two potential files to (save and then) delete, to see if the situation improves: - `<workspace>/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/workbench.xmi`
- `<workspace>/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.ui.workbench.prefs`

Comment: Ok, I can confirm this behavior in Eclipse Juno SR2. I don't see anything in the release notes to indicate that this would be expected behavior. You might want to file a bug report.

Comment: Same here -- this is annoying!  I've found several bugs reported on Eclipse with lengthy discussions but apparently no resolution!

Comment: Older Eclipse bugs: [bug 375744](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=375744), [bug 283345](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=283345).

Comment: I can confirm this behavior in Kepler... just closed eclipse by mistake (cmd-q is just "one key away" from cmd-q)! Very annoying, any new concerning to this "bug" (there seem to be several bugs - some reported as fixed, some reopen - in eclipse bugs).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

OK, so having the same problem with Safari and doing a google search led me to [this Apple discussions page](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3685337?start=0&tstart=0). Basically following these steps (via @evenhuis) you can re-map the quit shortcut to any other menu function:

1. Go to System Preference > Keyboard.
2. Choose Keyboard Shortcuts
3. Click Application Shortcuts
4. Press the + button
5. Under Application choose Eclipse
6. For Menu Title input "Show All".  (You could use some
   other innocuous menu option here)
7. For Short Cut use ⌘Q

Comment: Excellent tip... however the "Bring All to Front" menu title did not work for me... but using the "Show All" (which is a option under the "Eclipse" menu - like the "quit") worked just perfect (maybe you should update the answer with that and mark it as completed)! Thank you for the tip!